# How Blazor server Guarantee the order of SignalR messages

Tags: signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I have a Blazor server application that reads data from an Iot device and show it in a page,

if the device send data every says 300ms i have no problems
but if the device send data every <2ms
i notice a difference between the real value of the device and the value shown in the page.

i know that blazor server uses signalR to sent data back and forth to the clients i also think that signalR does not ensure the order of messages.

i want to know if the blazor team did something to ensure that order of signalR messages
or that should be done manually

Comment: "signalR does not ensure the order of messages". That is incorrect, SignalR does guarantee order of messages, what it doesn't guarantee is message delivery. For example if the server sends a message the client might disconnect before receiving the message and SignalR wont replay the lost message unless you write a system to do that yourself.